# Pandas how to group by day and other column

Tags: pandas

I am getting the daily counts of rows from a dataframe using

```
df = df.groupby(by=df['startDate'].dt.date).count()
```

How can I modify this so I can also group by another column 'unitName'?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.groupby([df['startDate'].dt.date, 'unitName']).size()
```

If need count non missing values, e.g. column `col` use [`DataFrameGroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html):

```
df = df.groupby([df['startDate'].dt.date, 'unitName'])['col'].count()
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I return a dataframe where all rows are populated?

Comment: @TheloniousMonk - Do you think `df = df.groupby([df['startDate'].dt.date, 'unitName']).size().reset_index(name='count')` ?